# What will be the bat script syntax to find conatiner id and stop the docker container

Tags: windows, docker, batch-file, containers

I have written this bat script but I am getting an error on the 3rd line.

```
for /f %%i in ('docker ps -qf "name=^demo-application"') do set containerId=%%i
echo %containerId%
If "%containerId%" == ""
echo "No Container running"
ELSE
docker stop %ContainerId%
docker rm -f %ContainerId%
```

[image]

Comment: Type `if /?` to learn the correct syntax…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` syntax is slightly off. The command has to be on the same (logical) line as the `if`. Also the `else` and the command after it has to be on the same (logical) line. Use parentheses to start a code-block (the start of a command block is syntactically treated as a valid command):

```
for /f %%i in ('docker ps -qf "name=^demo-application"') do set containerId=%%i
echo %containerId%
If "%containerId%" == "" (
  echo "No Container running"
) ELSE (
  docker stop %ContainerId%
  docker rm -f %ContainerId%
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, without having to `set` a variable:

```
for /f %%i in ('docker ps -qf "name=^demo-application"') do If not "%%i" == "" (
    docker stop %%i
    docker rm -f %%i
  ) else (
    echo "No Container running"
)
```